# Proof check for $\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}}\mathcal{P} (X)=\mathcal{P} \bigl(\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}}X\bigr)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

To be proved: $$\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}}\mathcal{P} (X)=\mathcal{P} \bigl(\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}}X\bigr),$$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is some nonempty set of sets, and $\mathcal{P} (X)$ stands for power set of $X$.

**Proof:**
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{P} (X)
& =\{ X:\forall Y(Y\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow X\in \mathcal{P} (Y))\}\\
& =\{ X:\forall Y(Y\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow X\subset Y)\}\\
& =\{ X:\forall Y(Y\in \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \forall x(x\in X \rightarrow x\in Y))\} \\
& =\{ X:\forall x(x\in X \rightarrow \forall Y(Y\in \mathcal{C}\rightarrow x\in Y))\}\\
& =\{ X:\forall x(x\in X\rightarrow x\in\bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal{C}} Y\}\\
& =\{ X:X\subset\bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal{C}} Y\}\\
& = \mathcal{P}\bigl(\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{C}} X\bigr)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it your way you should start with something like:$$\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}\wp\left(X\right)=\left\{ A\mid\forall X\in\mathcal{C}\left[A\in\wp\left(X\right)\right]\right\} $$

You "overuse" symbol $X$.

---

My way:

For every set $A$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $A\in\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}\wp\left(X\right)$
- $A\in\wp\left(X\right)$ for every $X\in\mathcal{C}$
- $A\subseteq X$ for every $X\in\mathcal{C}$
- $A\subseteq\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X$
- $A\in\wp\left(\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X\right)$

Then based on equivalence of statements under first and last bullet for every set $A$ we conclude:$$\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}\wp\left(X\right)=\wp\left(\bigcap_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X\right)$$This on base of the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: But, is *my* proof correct?

Comment: Yes (in my edit of your question I repaired what I think was a typo), formally it is correct (if $\subset$ is the same to you as $\subseteq$). Though the $4$-th equality is quite a big step that actually needs a proof. Concerning the appearance personally I would avoid the $\to$ sign and would go for $\forall Y\in\mathcal C[\cdots]$ instead of $\forall Y[Y\in\mathcal C\to[\cdots]]$. Same story for $\forall x[x\in X\to[\cdots]]$ that can be written as $\forall x\in X[\cdots]$.